# How to use File.open inside a Rails Rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I need to create a recurring task that creates (or edits) product records from an external text file. From inside irb:

```
>> f = File.open(<filename>) # file in same directory path
```

No issues.

But when pasted into a Rake task file, the script always bombs "File not found". (Rails 3.1, Ubuntu.)

```
namespace :sap do
  desc "uploads data from raw SAP file"
  task :upload => :environment do
     f = File.open("sap_pnlist_20111010a.csv")
     records = f.readlines
     records.each {|row|
     ... etc etc ...
     }
  end
end
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Either give it a full path or use [`Rails.root.join`](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/root/class) if the file is somewhere inside your Rails root.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks Jordan!

Comment: Why don't you make this an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file is somewhere inside your Rails root, use

```
Rails.root.join('grandparent_dir', 'parent_dir', 'file.txt')
```

If the file is not in your Rails root, **you must give it the full path**.